# Even after trying multiple times i am unable to get correct answer for this graph question?

Tags: graph, networkx, graph-theory

Select all True statements.

1. We can use subsets of node-pairs to approximate betweenness centrality.
2. The closeness centrality of a node describes how far the node is from others.
3. In directed networks, in-degree and out-degree centrality of a node are always the same.
4. The assumption of degree centrality is that important nodes have more connections.
5. The node with highest betweenness centrality in a network also has the highest closeness centrality.

**According to me option 1,4,5 should be correct , but it is always showing as wrong.**

Comment: 2 of your selections are wrong, and you are missing a correct one.

Comment: maybe  2 and 4?  following on Paul's suggetion.